# Why does a View's margins still influence a layout while GONE?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `LinearLayout` and a `FrameLayout` inside with some margin. The strange thing is that even though `visibility` is set to `GONE` the inner view's margin seems to have an influence on the elemtns surrounding it. This is just the case in runtime, not during design time in the IDE.

Android documentation states:

> GONE - This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes

1. So why does margin still have an influence?
2. What sense does it make (if it has any)?
3. And most importantly: How do I accomplish a view completely vanishing and have no effect whatsoever on its neighbours?

Of course you can just set the margin to 0 in code but that's really inconvenient when you have to toggle visibility frequently and maintaining correct margins.

Here is the layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cardLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/cardContentStack"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cardImageLarge"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/card_image_big_height"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/card_image_big_bottom_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_base"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_base"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:src="@drawable/some_image"
            tools:visibility="visible" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/cardImageWrapper"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_base">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/cardImage"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/card_image_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/card_image_size"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    tools:src="@drawable/some_image2"
                    tools:visibility="visible" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/cardImageSmall"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/card_image_small_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/card_image_small_size"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_base"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    tools:src="@drawable/some_image3"
                    tools:visibility="visible" />

            </FrameLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/cardBodyContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/cardTextContainer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_base"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_base"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/card_title_top_margin">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <com.company.android.text.textview.BodyMedium
                            android:id="@+id/cardTitle"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:textColor="@color/midnight"
                            tools:text="Michele Theisen" />

                        <FrameLayout
                            android:id="@+id/cardTitleRightSpacer"
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/card_title_right_spacer"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:visibility="gone"
                            tools:visibility="visible">

                        </FrameLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <com.company.android.text.textview.BodyLittle
                        android:id="@+id/cardBody"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/card_title_top_margin"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:maxLines="2"
                        android:textColor="@color/twilight"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        tools:text="Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text"
                        tools:visibility="visible" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/cardButtonContainer"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_small"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_small"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_small"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    tools:visibility="visible">

                    <com.company.views.materialstextviews.CardButton
                        android:id="@+id/cardSecondaryButton"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/card_action_button_height"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_small"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_xs"
                        android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_xs"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textColor="@color/twilight"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        tools:text="BUTTON TEXT MIGHT BE LONG"
                        tools:visibility="visible" />

                    <com.company.views.materialstextviews.CardButton
                        android:id="@+id/cardPrimaryButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/card_action_button_height"
                        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_xs"
                        android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_xs"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textColor="@color/green"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        tools:text="BUTTON TEXT"
                        tools:visibility="visible" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cardCloseButton"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/card_close_button_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/card_close_button_size"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_card_close"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

`cardImageWrapper` is the view that causes the problem.

Comment: Could you post your layout .xml file. I would also say margin should go away with the view.

Comment: Have you tried using padding instead of margin?

Comment: @KevinLEGOFF OK, I added the layout file

Comment: @Larpee In some cases I use negative margins and that I can't accomplish with paddings.